How frequently would false dependencies occur without register renaming?
Given an out-of-order processor without register renaming, how frequently would false dependencies occur? I've been trying to find papers that actually measure this, but I have found nothing. AI Searches give vague answers.
In particular, do logical registers that are changed frequently cause more issues than ones with long-lives values? By how much?
